# Update the POST endpoint with additional input without hampering existing functionality in .Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

Consider the scenario where I have a POST endpoint which takes an `ID` in route parameter and a specific request payload `Range`. I want to update this endpoint to also include an additional parameter `Type` by providing it into POST request payload.

I have considered multiple options here:

- Updating the route parameter to provided additional parameter in route.
  `[Route("updateItem/{id:int}/{type}")]`.
- Changing the request payload DTO `Range` on server and update the existing consumers.
- Using `[FromBody]` in the controller arguments.

However these approaches will hamper the existing consumers of the API.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("updateItem/{id:int}")]
 public IHttpActionResult UpdateItem(int id, Range range) 
 { 
    return Ok(Service.UpdateItem(id, range)); 
 }
```

Is there a way to pass on the information of `Type` to the API without impacting existing consumers of the API ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
 [Route("updateItem/{id:int}"/{type:Type?})]
 public IHttpActionResult UpdateItem(int id, Type? type=null, Range range) 
 { 
 if (type != null)
{ 
    return Ok(Service.UpdateItem(id, range)); 
    }
    else
    {
    //implementation for type parameter
    }
 }
```

Comment: While this works and I also tried this, I am wondering is  this the cleanest way yo do it. Is there a way possible to do it without altering the route URL?

Comment: If you don't want to change the route URL,you can add the value of Type  into body,and use `[FromBody]Type type`.